Warning: Additionally, the fallback loader failed to parse the XML
While setting up Android environment in Qt, the following warning pops up:
Warning: Additionally, the fallback loader failed to parse the XML.
I already had a well setup and running Android environment. I upgraded to Qt 6.7 recently and tried to run application in already installed Emulator as well as actual android device. The application dies right before the launch of debugger. So I decided to remove and reinstall Android component of Qt, JDK, SDK and its system images. Doing so produces the above warning and application dies as usual.
Qt version - 6.7,
JDK version - 17,
SDK version - 25.1.8937393 & 26.1.10909125
I have tried installing system images of different APIs and deleting the cache folder of Qt.

